# MutationObserver получить атрибуты дочерних элементов - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток!
Собственно нужна помощь знающих людей!
Собственно в чем проблема, не могу достать атрибут дочернего элемента.

```
var botInv = document.querySelector( '#bots_inv' );
    var observer = new MutationObserver( function( mutations ) { 
        mutations.forEach( function( mutation ) { 
            //console.log( mutation.type );
            if( mutation.type == 'childList' ) {
                for( var m = 0; m < mutation.addedNodes.length; m++ ) {
                    var thisitm = mutation.addedNodes[m];
                    //data-sell - процент вывода под ОПС
                    //data-buy - процент завода на LF
                    console.log( $(thisitm)[0] );   
                }           
            }
        } );
    } );
    var obsConfig = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true/*, subtree: true*/ };
    observer.observe( botInv, obsConfig );
```

В консоли выводится:

```
<div class="itemwrap">...</div>
<div class="itemwrap">...</div>
<div class="itemwrap">...</div>
<div class="itemwrap">...</div>
<div class="itemwrap">...</div>
```

Вроде все как надо, но вот уже из этих блоков я не могу достать атрибут

```
"data_sell"
```

из блока

```
class="parse_button parse_done"
```

Код блока "itemwrap"

```
<div class="itemwrap"><div class="itemblock unstable_checked" id="b7797f94_0" data-p="220215" data-name="AWP | Dragon Lore (Minimal Wear)"><img class="it_image" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/2758700128/96fx96f" srcset="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/2758700128/96fx96fdpx2x 2x"><div class="it_name WA">AWP | Dragon Lore</div><div class="it_price price105"><b>$2202.15</b></div><div class="it_bot">7</div><div class="it_ext">MW</div><div class="it_s"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/community01/headhunter_foil.cc6995e01e0471d46a1bc550e9d2ad7f076784bc.png"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/krakow2017/sig_adrenkz_gold.0ae91bd5ffc15ffa8f5b940cf8faaeedaae19465.png"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/stickers2/crown_foil.77c38fe60426ee084fd5c8fec0c680c342e05743.png"></div><div class="parse_button parse_done" data_sell="-35.63" data_buy="26.33" style="background-color: transparent"><div class="parse_indicator green_indicator" title="LootFarm > OPSkins">-35.63%</div><div class="parse_indicator red_indicator" title="OPSkins > LootFarm">26.33%</div></div></div></div>
```

Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить такую строку

`console.log($(thisitm).find('.parse_button.parse_done').attr('data_sell'));`

Comment: Не работает, консоль выдает "undefined"

Comment: Так тоже пробовал, там выдает ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].find is not a function"

Comment: @Бесенок а так `$('.thisitm').first().find...` ?

Comment: Нет, так же пишет "undefined", да и "thisitm" же не класс, а переменная

Comment: а какое количество найденных элементов `find`-ом?

Comment: 101 такого вида `jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: div.itemwrap, selector: ".parse_button.parse_done"]`

Comment: @Бесенок у них есть атрибут data_sell?

Comment: Этот атрибут есть только у блока `parse_button parse_done` который вложен в `<div class='itemblock'>` который в свою очередь вложен в `<div class="itemwrap">`

Comment: @Бесенок так `find` разве не эти элементы вернул?

Comment: Он вернул то что я написал выше, когда вешаешь на find(...).attr(...) то выдает `undefined`

Comment: @Бесенок ну так раскройте в консоли объект, посмотрите что он содержит

Comment: Там куча функций типа `accessKey:"" align:"" assignedSlot:null`, но того что мне нужно нет

Comment: @Бесенок attributes откройте

Comment: Там только `class` и `style` причем они почему то принадлежат блоку `itemwrap`